# Space consumption of each child dataset snapshot after zfs snapshot -r

Tags: freebsd, zfs

after performing `zfs snapshot -r zpool@myRecursiveSnapshot`

will, for example, the `zpool/usr@myRecursiveSnapshot` and `zpool/var@myRecursiveSnapshot` snapshots take up space in addition to `zpool@myRecursiveSnapshot`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. A recursive snapshot creates a snapshot in the child filesystems in the same way that it would if you took a snapshot of each child filesystem separately.

Initially, the snapshot consumes very little additional space. As the filesystems change, however, the snapshots consume more space because the original data must also be stored to maintain the snapshot.